# How can I find all combinations with a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Python 3.9.5

I wrote the following code:

```
pattern_space = '[\s]+'
pattern_name= '(.{4,})'
pattern =  pattern_name + pattern_space + '(street|town){1}' + pattern_space + pattern_name
result = re.search(pattern, 'Boston town street Coco')
```

And I have got:

> Boston

> town

> street Coco

I also want to get a valid variant:

> Boston town

> street

> Coco

How can I get ALL the possible variants?

Answer (score 1):

With PyPi regex and infinite width lookbehind:

```py
import regex
pattern =  r'(?<=^(.*)\W)(street|town)(?=\W*(.*))'
result = regex.findall(pattern, 'Boston town street Coco')
print(result)
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##LczBCsIwDIDh@54ityZDdvFqGehD7DKEoVULNSlphgq@e3XO88//5ZfdhLe1xnsWNdBwDc8mT2ZBGTyAOux3/ohdS@NAWExDsLfJgwl7Pw7tUsg1Gsqc7Hv8hO4S@TylhH9pA24vxYRhOWFV4CAncdRkjWy4AlTrBw).

**Results**: `[('Boston', 'town', 'street Coco'), ('Boston town', 'street', 'Coco')]`

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \W                       non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-
                             9, _)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    street                   'street'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    town                     'town'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \W*                      non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-
                             9, _) (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```